# Global.asax Error handling: Quirks of server.transfer

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, global-asax

In my global.asax, I am checking for a 404, and transferring to the 404 error page as per the below:

```
    If HTTPExceptionInstance.GetHttpCode = 404 Then

        Server.ClearError()

        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True
        Response.Status = "404 Not Found"

        Server.Transfer("~/Invalid-Page.aspx")

    End If
```

The problem is, my Invalid-page.aspx uses some **session code** (Session("somevariable")), which throws an exception *"Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. "* because I am using a server.transfer (I believe this is a known issue?).

If I use a Response.Redirect, there is **no** problem. However, this would mean that the header of the error page is a 200, not a 404.

What would be the best workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weird! Server.TransferRequest does exactly what I want without losing the session state!

Comment: Thank you! This has been bugging me for hours. The semantic of `TransferRequest` is different than of `Transfer` (e.g. it apparently creates a new `HttpContext`, thus any `Items` in the current context are lost), but it is a good workaround for the lost session problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if EnableSessionState is set to true in the page directive of Invalid.aspx

Comment: I've added it, but it didn't make a difference. As I understand it, the problem seems to be caused due to server.transfer, which seems to be killing the session...