# Server.Transfer not working in Application_Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404, server.transfer

I am redirecting to Error 404 page and want to issue 404 as a response code for google engine.

We are using ***IIS 6 in production environment*** :(

Code does 404 Handling in Global.ascx.cs in `Application_Error()`

```
if ((ex is HttpException && 404 == ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode()))
 {
    //Server.Transfer("~/404.aspx"); // Error with session state 
    Server.TransferRequest("~/404.aspx"); //This operation requires IIS 7 
    //Response.Redirect("~/404.aspx"); It will issue 302 then 404
     return;
 }
```

**Server.Transfer**

> Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true,
>   either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also
>   make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state
>   module is included in the `<configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules>`
>   section in the application configuration.

**Response.Redirect**

> Issues 302 since it does client side redirect and then 404. I want to
>   skip 302

**Server.TransferRequest**

> This operation requires IIS integration pipeline mode

[Global.asax Error handling: Quirks of server.transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620530/global-asax-error-handling-quirks-of-server-transfer)

***How can I deal this problem in IIS 6?***

why i am getting session issue with `Server.Transfer`? Is there a valid reason behind or it is a bug in ASP.Net Framework?

Answer (score -2):

If you still need correct 404 redirection, you can use this code:

```
Response.AddHeader("Location", "~/404.aspx");
Response.Status = "404 Not found";
```